# Track how long a thread spent actually working on a future

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I would like to keep track of how long a thread in a `ThreadPoolExecutor` spend working on a piece of code that I submitted to the pool, not how long the work item spent sitting in the pool. I, of course, call `future.result()` to get the result, but I was hoping there was some way I could call `future.time()` or something like that to get the execution time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a simple wrapper that does this:

```
def timed(func):
    def _w(*a, **k):
        then = time.time()
        res = func(*a, **k)
        elapsed = time.time() - then
        return elapsed, res
    return _w
```

Then you invoke your future e.g. with `executor.map(timed(is_prime), PRIMES))` (example taken from the docs).

Of course then you need to unpack the resulting timestamp & result

```
elapsed, result = future.result()
```

Comment: This is mostly what I imagined I'd end up doing in my head. Do you think this could be a decorator somehow?

Comment: It matter of factly is a decorator already. Just use it as one with `@timed` ;) I didn't want to impose this as I don't know if those functions you want to time will always ever be the entry points of futures. I personally would explicitly wrap them as I showed, because it separates the concerns cleanly IMHO, but that's your decision of course.

Answer (score 1):

The one of possible ways is to use a shared structure to capture time execution statistics for each thread.
Consider the following example (calculation of *factorials* for 10 consecutive numbers in parallel):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from threading import current_thread
from functools import partial
import time
import random
import math
import pprint

def fact(time_dict, num):
    t0 = time.time()
    res = math.factorial(num)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))

    time_dict[current_thread().name] = time.time() - t0
    return res

time_dict = {}
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10, thread_name_prefix='thread') as executor:
    factorials = executor.map(partial(fact, time_dict), range(1, 11))
    pprint.pprint(['result: ', list(factorials)])
    pprint.pprint(['timings:', time_dict])
```

Sample output:

```
['result: ', [1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]]
['timings:',
 {'thread_0': 2.005145788192749,
  'thread_1': 2.004167079925537,
  'thread_2': 5.0020458698272705,
  'thread_3': 4.004181146621704,
  'thread_4': 3.0027127265930176,
  'thread_5': 5.001489877700806,
  'thread_6': 3.002448797225952,
  'thread_7': 5.001359224319458,
  'thread_8': 2.005021095275879,
  'thread_9': 2.0049009323120117}]
```

Comment: Great idea to use shared data like this, but I need something more granular on a `future` by `future` basis.